# grid search with early stopping - influence of validation data to grid search results?

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, keras, optimal-stopping

I would like to combine grid search with early stopping by passing a separate validation data set (used for early stopping) to grid search.

However, I wonder when I use during the entire grid search always the same validation data for early stopping, would not be indirectly the search for optimal hyperparameters be influenced through this validation data?
I mean wouldn't information from this validation
data set flow indirectly into this search?

(I'm using GridSearchCV from Skicit-learn and
EarlyStopping from Keras)

Comment: Yes, as any decision made from the validation data. An additional test data set helps to assess the size of this overfit.

Comment: @Michael M     Yes, I have a separate test data set, which is only used for testing the final model and therefore does not come into contact with grid search.  But during the model search via grid search I always use the same validation data set for early stopping, so I don't vary as in k-fold-cross-validation. And here I ask myself to what extent the model is adapted to this validation data set? Perhaps is using early stopping in grid search a bad idea?